# How does VBScript measure time that its sleeping?

Tags: vbscript

So just for fun I decided to write a vbs that will play a snake game for me! Only problem is is that every time it runs the loop, it runs differently.

```
set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WScript.Sleep(3000)
WshShell.SendKeys "{up}"
WshShell.SendKeys "{right}"
WScript.Sleep(770)
DIM REP
REP = 0
DO WHILE REP < 3

WshShell.SendKeys "{DOWN}"
WshShell.SendKeys "{LEFT}"
 WScript.Sleep(770)
WshShell.SendKeys "{DOWN}"
WshShell.SendKeys "{Right}"
 WScript.Sleep(770)
WshShell.SendKeys "{DOWN}"
WshShell.SendKeys "{LEFT}"
WScript.Sleep(770)
WshShell.SendKeys "{DOWN}"
WshShell.SendKeys "{Right}"
 WScript.Sleep(770)
WshShell.SendKeys "{DOWN}"
WshShell.SendKeys "{LEFT}"
 WScript.Sleep(860)
WshShell.SendKeys "{UP}"
 WScript.Sleep(400)
WshShell.SendKeys "{RIGHT}"
WScript.Sleep(800)
REP = REP + 1
LOOP
```

My Code looks like this but my question is how does the timing work? Like why does the second loop run into a wall when it runs? Or if it makes it, which sometimes it does, it crashes on the third loop and so on. Why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know timing is measured in milliseconds for VB scripting. You mention the second loop runs into a wall? I only see one loop??

From what I see your timing between key presses is 0 (No pause between key presses) If i remember the game snake correctly you can only move up, down, left and right respectively.

The key presses in the loop here seem to be creating diagonals? (EX: downRight, downLeft due to no "time" between key presses) Perhaps that's the real issue? Try adding sleeps between key presses to see if that solves the issue?